# What is this Lead (Pb, metal) cable called and why is it used?

Tags: electrical

The kitchen ceiling is being replaced and has uncovered some curios.  The most interesting being the 1' lump of cast-iron bath that fell on the plasterer, but the other...

[image: LeadPbCable]

... is this Lead (the metal, Pb) cable that is running through the ground floor ceiling of a UK home from around 1920's.  Photo is taken below 15mm pipework for scale.

Can anyone identify it and explain its use?  I've tried to google for an answer, but as lead is a homograph for a type of cabe, I've had little luck.

Thanks,
James

Comment: Can you give us a photo of the inside of one of the boxes these cables terminate in?

Comment: Those cable clips look relatively modern (not 1920s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is lead clad electrical cable.  It was generally used for underground wiring back in the day, however I've occasionally seen it used indoors.  Likely a case of "Well, we already have this so might as well use it."

I've also seen something similar that contained telephone pairs, but I doubt a home would need that many phone lines.

Comment: Thanks, Connor - that's what it is.  It's much easier to search when you have the correct term!  Seems as though the use of lead is primarily to protect against moisture.  You learn something new everyday!

Comment: Pre-plastics, flexible sheathing wasn't such an easy thing to achieve. If you didn't need waterproof, fabric would work, but...

Comment: @keshlam yes, the insulation inside is probably rubberised fabric. And the rubber has probably perished

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the United States is loaded with lead landline telephony cables:
http://archive.today/MA0wG
WSJ: "America Is Wrapped in Miles of Toxic Lead Cables"

Comment: The problem with being a world leader in technology is that you have to deal with the legacy of having installed all the earliest versions of it and the economics of recovering/recycling it. There's still lead plumbing in some places too. What we need is a sudden global demand for lead to raise its price to the point where the recovery is justified by money as well as health reasons...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).